# Convert php array to xml

Tags: php

please review my code, i have tried several suggestion on various threads, i either get a blank out put or a string.

**my code**

```
   <?php
       $input_array = array (
         'name' => 'John Doe',
         'course' => 'Computer Science',
         'age' => 'twenty one'
        );
       $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
       array_walk_recursive(array_flip($input_array), array ($xml, 'addChild'));
       print $xml->asXML();
    ?>
```

**output**
John DoeComputer Sciencetwenty one

Comment: I'd suggest doing this with a `for` or `foreach` loop instead of trying to make a one-liner with `array_walk_recursive`.

Answer (score 1):

The web browser is parsing the tags which is why they appear to not be there.

Right click and view source. Or surround the output with `<pre>` tags.

```
print '<pre>';
print $xml->asXML();
print '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $input_array = array (
                   'name' => 'John Doe',
                   'course' => 'Computer Science',
                   'age' => 'twenty one'
                  );

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
    $arr = array_flip($input_array);
    array_walk_recursive($arr, array( $xml, 'addChild'));
                       //^^^ Can't use array_filp directly otherwise: Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

    print $xml->asXML();

?>
```

To get a nice formatted output you could do this:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <name>John Doe</name>
  <course>Computer Science</course>
  <age>twenty one</age>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was the content type that I didn't specify that caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

a short one:

```
<?php

$test_array = array (
  'bla' => 'blub',
  'foo' => 'bar',
  'another_array' => array (
    'stack' => 'overflow',
  ),
);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive($test_array, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
print $xml->asXML();
```

results in

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <blub>bla</blub>
  <bar>foo</bar>
  <overflow>stack</overflow>
</root>
```

For converting php array to xml refer [this doc](http://www.lalit.org/lab/convert-php-array-to-xml-with-attributes/) in that very good solution available